# Limit of $a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_n^3}{1+a_n^4}$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

Let $a_1$ be real, and define $$a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_n^3}{1+a_n^4}$$ How can I prove that this $\{a_n\}$ to have limit.

I find it is hard to track. What I can do is just when $a_1=1$ then $a_n=1$; when $a_1=-1$, then $a_n=-1$; when $|a_1|<1$, $a_n\to 0$. When $|a_1|>1$, I have not find any idea.

Comment: Did you plot on the same diagram the functions $y=x$ and $y=2x^3/(1+x^4)$? What did this diagram tell you?

Comment: The following does not prove the limit exists, but tells you what it can possibly be when it exists, which may guide you for existence. Suppose the limit exists and is $L$. Taking limits of both sides you get $L=\frac{2L^3}{1+L^4}$. Equivalently $L(1+L^4)=2L^3$. There is the trivial solution $L=0$, and the rest are found by dividing by $L$ and solving a quadratic in $L^2$. You might also see that $\pm1$ are solutions directly from the equation, or from what you've already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given the recursion
$$a_0:=a>0,\qquad a_{n+1}:=f(a_n)\quad(n\geq0)$$
with 
$$f(x):={2x^3\over 1+x^4}\ .$$
The following figure shows the graph of $f$ for $x\geq0$:

[image]

Since
$$f(x)\geq0,\qquad x-f(x)={x(1-x^2)^2\over 1+x^4}\geq0$$
(with strict inequality unless $x=0$ or $x=1$), we deduce that the the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is  monotonically decreasing towards a limit $\alpha\geq0$. This limit necessarily satisfies $f(x)=x$, whence $\alpha\in\{0,1\}$, and may depend on the starting value $a$.

It follows that for $0<a<1$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

When $a=1$ one has $a_n=1$ for all $n\geq0$.

In order to analyze the case $a>1$ we write $f$ in the form
$$f(x)=1+{x-1\over1+x^4}(1+x+x^2-x^3)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here the right hand side is $>1$ for $1<x<\xi\doteq1.83929$, where $\xi$ is the real zero of the polynomial on the right of $(1)$, and is $<1$ when $x>\xi$; see also the figure.

It follows that for $1<a<\xi$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$. When $a=\xi$ we obtain $a_1=1$ and then $a_n=1$ for all $n\geq1$. When $a>\xi$ then $a_1<1$ and as a consequence $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to consider $a_n > 0$, as otherwise you could do the same analysis with $b_n = -a_n$ and $a_1=0 \iff a_n=0$, so that's trivial.

Note that $1+x^4 \ge 2x^2$ by AM-GM with equality iff $x=1$, so we have $a_{n+1} < a_n$, unless $a_k=1 \implies a_{n> k}=1$.  Thus we have a decreasing, positive (i.e. bounded) sequence ...

Comment: Year. It is that easy to show the convergence, but when $|a_1|>1$, you just know that $|a_{n+1}|\leq |a_n|$, and thus the limit exists. But how can I prove the limit is $0$, not $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: I thought you wanted to prove only existence of the limit.  Anyway, it is **not necessary that the limit is $0$**.  For e.g. if you start with $a_1$ to be the only real root of $x^3-x^2-x=1$ which is $\approx 1.8393$, you will get $a_2 = 1$, so all subsequent values and the limit becomes $1$ after that.